# Batch finding files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Here I have some code which finds all .m4a files and echoes the filename minus the first three characters:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (*.m4a) do (
set oldName=%%a
set newName=!oldName:~3!
echo !newName!
)
```

However, I want to do this only for files starting in 1 or 0. I know I could use

```
for %%a in (0*.m4a) do (
```

for just files starting in 0, but how do I make it for both 1 and 0? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%a in (0*.m4a 1*.m4a) do (
```

Just include it in the `for` set

But `for` over a set of files is dynamic. It is possible that the new named files are processed twice if their new name matches the wildcard expression in the `for` loop. To avoid it (if necessary), retrieve a static list with a `dir` command and process the list of files.

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d 0*.m4a 1*.m4a') do (
    set "oldName=%%a"
    set "newName=!oldName:~3!"
    ren "%%a" "!newName!"
)
```

Comment: hey, sorry to add to the question, but do you know how to rename the file then to newName? I tried ren %%a !newName! but it didn't work

Comment: @user3764734, the same code. In this case `%%a` will return the filename, so `ren "%%a" "!newName!"`

Comment: @user3764734, It didn't work for you? Which error do you get?

Comment: Oh, sorry I tried  `ren %%a !newName!` then added that as an edit to my comment before I saw yours, with the quotes around them

Answer (score 0):

Your code only needs a small modification.  One thing to be aware of is that the short filenames are matched as well as the long filenames by all forms of DIR and FOR commands.

A solution to that is to pipe the command through a findstr filter, if it is needed.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (0*.m4a 1*.mp4) do (
   set oldName=%%a
   set newName=!oldName:~3!
   echo !newName!
)
```