# For loop in batch file won't stop

Tags: windows, loops, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

My for loop just keeps going and going. I'm guessing around 6 times till it quits. With 14,000 files, that takes some time. All I want it to do is do it once. Just once, not to do it again and again. I've tested with a directory of 6 files and it eventually quits, but by that time it has repeated itself numerous times.

Here is the code for use in the command prompt (I have removed the %% which was in the batch file).

```
start "Adjustments 1" cmd /C "FOR %a in (*.png) DO magick %a -adaptive-sharpen 0x5 modified\adaptive_sharpen2_%a & FOR %a in (*.png) DO magick %a -adaptive-blur 0x1 modified\adaptive_blur_%a"
```

Please, how do I get this to only process the files once instead of processing each png multiple times and continually overwriting?

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir *.png') do ...` to create the list of files before actually processing them

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25832207/2152082) with some explanation. [Another one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17205285/2152082)

Comment: @Stephan I am writing the files to a different directory, so the new files shouldn't be seen? I will try your above code and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: @Compo, thank you. **This:** "I don't understand why you're joining a for loop to the end of another, when they're enumerating the exact same file listing. Would this not do the same thing: Start "Adjustments 1" cmd.exe /S /Q /D /C "For %G In (*.png) Do (magick.exe "%G" -adaptive-sharpen 0x5 "modified\adaptive_sharpen2_%~G" & magick.exe "%G" -adaptive-blur 0x1 "modified\adaptive_blur_%~G")"" **is the answer!** How do I accept a comment as an answer? Also, I looked at cmd /? and couldn't figure out these /S /Q /D and finally what is the difference between %~G and %G? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performing the task how you'd intended, you should isolate one `for` loop from the other. This can be done using parentheses:

```bash
Start "Adjustments 1" cmd.exe /S /Q /D /C "(For %G In (*.png) Do magick.exe "%G" -adaptive-sharpen 0x5 "modified\adaptive_sharpen2_%~G") & For %G In (*.png) Do magick.exe "%G" -adaptive-blur 0x1 "modified\adaptive_blur_%~G""
```

However, I don't understand why you're joining a `for` loop to the end of another, when they're enumerating the exact same file listing. It is just inefficient to do it like that.

Would this not do the same thing:

```bash
Start "Adjustments 1" cmd.exe /S /Q /D /C "For %G In (*.png) Do (magick.exe "%G" -adaptive-sharpen 0x5 "modified\adaptive_sharpen2_%~G" & magick.exe "%G" -adaptive-blur 0x1 "modified\adaptive_blur_%~G")"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what is happening is that the FOR loop is evaluating the *.png list each iteration, and is picking up your modified files because their date/time modified has changed.

I don't know enough about CMD scripts to write code for you, but you should be able to use the DIR command to list the *.png files, directing the output to a new file. Then, use FOR with the /F option to loop through that file one line at a time.

I also don't know the syntax of the magick program you are using to modify the file, but there might be an option to specify the exact name of the output. If so, you could output the files with another extension (or, another directory).

Comment: Stephan beat me to it....

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have them going to another directory called modified. I did that to preempt this behaviour. It also renames the files, so if it was processing the new files, I would get multiple files with new names appended multiple times, but I don't. So it is actually reprocessing only the original files multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that you use different `metavariable` names for the two `for` loops - you've used `%a` for both, but the second `for` is invoked with `%a` in-context.